# Trying to configure Network Card to have IP address

Tags: networking, linux-mint, network-interface, ip

I am a new Linux Mint user and my laptop so far only works with wifi and does not work with wired ethernet.

When I type `ifconfig -a` I get the following:

```
enp0s25: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
         ether 3c:97:0e:c9:ba:f9  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
         RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
         TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
         device interrupt 20  memory 0xf2500000-f2520000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
         inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
         inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
         loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
         RX packets 6110  bytes 617923 (617.9 KB)
         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
         TX packets 6110  bytes 617923 (617.9 KB)
         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
         inet 192.168.100.193  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.100.255
         inet6 fe80::2c47:45b4:9fed:9a4e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
         ether a4:4e:31:85:3a:50  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
         RX packets 3067404  bytes 4402855268 (4.4 GB)
         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
         TX packets 1505375  bytes 112689728 (112.6 MB)
         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

My friend tells me that `enp0s25` is not showing a IP address and that is why the ethernet cable is not working.  So I try to assign a IP address to the card by following the instructions on this link:
https://www.ostechnix.com/configure-static-ip-address-linux-unix/

The problem now, however, is that when I go to `/etc` folder I can't find a `sysconfig` folder.  What is going on?  Where is my `sysconfig` folder? Where can I find my `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s25` file?

Inside the file of `/etc/network/interfaces` is the following lines:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo eth0
iface lo inet loopback
```

How do I configure `enp0s25`?

Comment: That file exists in Fedora, RHEL, CentOS whereas you are using Mint. Like Debian and Ubuntu, the file for configuring your network interfaces is `/etc/network/interfaces`. Add the contents of the file to your question and use code blocks.

Comment: hi yes i've copy and pasted the contents of /etc/network/interfaces to the question now. thank you

Comment: I've edited the content of your `interfaces` file to make it readable. The `~` lines are not content -- that you're editor telling you that no line exists.  Please double check that what is here is what you have.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the Network Interface card to work with the ethernet LAN by working on the following file /etc/network/interfaces

I had to change the permission for the file...

Then using a editor like: vim 
I added the following lines of code:

```
auto enp0s25
    iface enp0s25 inet static
    address 192.168.100.99
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.100.1
    dns-nameservers 202.69.174.190 4.4.2.2
```

enp0s25 being the port name when I do netstat -i
and 192.168.100.1 being the IP address of the router
and the value for the dns-nameserver I used http://www.whatsmydnsserver.com/ to find.  Replace the xxx with whatever number you get from that website.

Then I restarted the network card

```
sudo systemctl restart networking
```

My question now is...how do I get the network interface to work automatically whenever I plug in the ETHERNET cable with internet to the ETHERNET slot....I odn't want to have to keep on configuring the network interface whenever I move location and work with a new router....

Comment: `chmod 777 interfaces` is both unnecessary and inadvisable.

Comment: true...any idea how to make this automatic?

Comment: for devices that move frequently (like a laptop), it would be more common to use `iface enp0s25 inet dhcp` instead of configuring `static`

Comment: Add a line `allow-hotplug enp0s25` to your `/etc/network/interfaces` file. See `man interfaces` on your system for more details. Background: `auto enp0s25` tells the system to configure this NIC when `systemd` initially starts the `networking.service` at boot. But the NIC driver may or may not be loaded at that point. `allow-hotplug enp0s25` says "configure this NIC whenever its driver gets loaded". (If your system actually uses NetworkManager, then this is automatically translated to "configure the NIC like this when it sees a valid link".)

Comment: Inside my interfaces file I got       `auto enp0s25
 iface enp0s25 inet dhcp`     and also this line at the end now     `allow-hotplug enp0s25`                    However I still keep on having to do `sudo systemctl restart networking`     every time I disconnect from the internet in order to reconnect.....what can I do to avoid having to keep on typing `sudo systemctl restart networking`
 ?